# Flask api - is there any way to perform some operation on different process and process leave all his occupied memory when ended

Tags: python, flask

I know that this question sound like similar other question on SO. but here I have concern regarding flask api memory management. Even I have removed object when their operation completed or when function scope ended. It will not released memory that occupied.

Here I add some screenshot of memory profiler.

```
161         **// Some Memory occupied when we Crete object but it will not releases when removed.**                                    
   162    140.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       if(data.get("accountType") == "QA"):
   163                                                 # with multiprocessing.Pool(1) as pool1:
   164                                                 #     cObject = pool1.map(getCassandraInstanceOfAwsBombay, [''])
   165    148.0 MiB      7.0 MiB           1           cObject = getCassandraInstanceOfAwsBombay()
   166    149.8 MiB      1.8 MiB           1           jsonData = common.getAIConsumerDetails(data,dfInter,dftransaction,cObject,int(startIndex),int(limit))
   167    149.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           cObject.discardsession()
   168    149.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1           cObject = None
   169                                                 
   170                                             
   171    149.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       if isinstance(jsonData, str):
   172                                                 raise ApiError(jsonData, status_code=410)
   173                                                 
   174                                         
   175    149.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       iFilename = None
   176    149.8 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       tFilename = None
   177            // **Only partial memory released when assign as None**                             
   178    149.7 MiB     -0.1 MiB           1       dftransaction = None
   179    146.6 MiB     -3.1 MiB           1       dfInter = None
   180    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       common = None
   181                                         
   182    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       del dfInter
   183    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       del dftransaction
   184                                         
   185                                         
   186    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       gc.collect()
   187    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       dfInter = pd.DataFrame()
   188    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       dftransaction = pd.DataFrame()
   189                                         
   190    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       mem1 = process.memory_info().rss
   191    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print('Memory Usage After Action',mem1/(1024**2),'MB')
   192    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       print('Memory Increase After Action',(mem1-mem0)/(1024**2),'MB')
   193                                                
   194    146.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       return {"data" : jsonData, "success" : 1}
```

Here I called gc.collect() even memory are not released. Can someone please tell me how to released fully occupied memory when it scope completed or we removed that object. I heard that there is way to release memory from heap.

I have read many tutorial regarding memory management but it wan't help me.

Thanks

Comment: CPython does not give memory back to the OS. It just frees it for internal reuse. (With the exception of loaded C libs).

Comment: Is memory causing a problem for you? Unless this is a specific advanced use-case, based on your profile I'm guessing you're coming into Python from other languages? Generally speaking you shouldn't ever need to manually handle memory.

Comment: Also bear in mind there's many ways to host a flask app, each one may handle the memory a bit differently.

Comment: @Peter, Yes,  I am trying different way to release manually because automatically I don't see any decrement in memory after sometime even my request endup. can you please provide way to host flask app different so may that help me. thanks

Comment: Have you checked what happens if you keep calling the same page, or call a hundred different pages, etc? It likely holds some stuff to make subsequent calls faster and frees things when needed, by attempting to free everything you could be causing a big performance hit. Gunicorn is one of the ways of hosting that's able to handle large amounts of traffic, Google Cloud Platform uses it if you deploy to their App Engine. I think you can also use pythonanywhere as a free alternative but I don't know much about it.

Comment: @Peter, memory is increased in every same api call but on that much that occupied in first call. Example if first request occupied 15 MB then second request need 9MB and third 5 MB and so on. but my question is that If it keep occupied for better performance so is it release once memory usage reach near to 100 % and for other process we need memory?

Comment: It probably doesn't go up to 100%, but honestly I'd say just trust it lol. Unless you are attempting to run it on some hardware with a tiny amount of memory, I think this falls under "premature optimisation", which will only make your life a ton harder in the future when your API gets more complex.